# MVC 5 Entity Framework 6, Trouble in Controller (CRUD)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have some controllers disabled in a strongly typed view. This view is strongly typed to my model I call `MyModel`. Some dropdowns are submitted on post and `ModelBinder` creates an object `M` that contains user selections. I compare this to the data before the selection, I call `cached_data`. If there's a change `!(cached_data.Property == Model.Property)`, I update the model.

Problem is it's not updating. Is there a way to fix this issue and or improve the code?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel M)
{
    var db = new MyModel();
    var cached_data = db.View.Find(M.ID);              

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //populate properties of model 
        //first compare to data before post request
        //if change occurred, update property              
        var db.MyModel.Property1 = !(db.MyModel.Property1 == cached_data.Property1) ?  M.Property1 : cached_data.Property1;                    
        //now update the database through EntityFramework 

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                  
            return View(e.InnerException);
        }
    }
    return View(M);
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any exceptions?

Comment: Niloy, unfortunately not. After debugging for 2 hours and setting several breakpoints I can't find the source of the error and no inner exception is generated. The view is returned and the update simply isn't made to the underlying db.

Comment: Is this valid C# `var db.Property1 = ...` ?

Comment: I'm confused by what MyModel is. You use it as your View Model, but also treat it like it's your DbContext. Can you show us the SaveChanges method?

Comment: tic - No, you're right. Fixed *

Comment: SeanOB : Not sure what you mean, SaveChanges is part of EntityFramework. It's true that the ViewModel and db context are derived from the same yes should be something like new db = MYMODEL(). Can't show code as not open source project.

Comment: if db.SaveChanges() is entity freamework then where you are initializing that object *db*? you have created one object *db* and you are using it for model and also for entity framework. how is it possible?

Comment: If there is a change or not you are saving db in both cases!

Comment: please add code for **MyModel**

Comment: MyModel  is dbcontext and Model too? i mean mixture of both?

Answer (score 0):

most Identity Framework templates will have you returned a value in the post from the view and Bind your model class to it like so

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(int companyId, [Bind("Color,CompanyId,ItemName,OrderNumb,Price,Qty,Size,Ordered")] Order order)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(order);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { CompanyId = order.CompanyId });
        }
        return View(order);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a wrong check - from the looks of it it seems to me that `db.MyModel` and `cache_data` are same according to these statements -

```
var db = new MyModel();
var cached_data = db.View.Find(M.ID);
```

So instead of comparing like this -

```
!(db.MyModel.Property1 == cached_data.Property1)
```

You really should be comparing `M`, as `M` is the changed data, so the check should be something like this  -

```
!(db.MyModel.Property1 == M.Property1) // M contained the new changes
```

or at least -

```
!(cached_data.Property1 == M.Property1) // M contained the new changes
```

I am answering based on your info, let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Typically the db variable is used for the entity that contains your Model. You should be looking up MyModel in that set and then update it so you don't have to worry if the values have been changed or not. Here is how I would rewrite this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel M)
{
    var db = new MyContextDB();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        MyModel myModel = db.MyModel.Where(m => m.ID == M.ID).FirstOrDefault();

        if (myModel != null)
        {
            db.Entry(mymodel).CurrentValues.SetValues(M);


            try
            {                
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                return View(e.InnerException);
            }
        }
    }
    return View(M);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your info lets assume `new MyModel()` is the `dbcontext` so when you do

```
var cached_data = db.View.Find(M.ID);
```

when you use `Find`  entity framework will track changes the returned object in your case its `cached_data` but you are saving changes in `var db.MyModel` which wont work so you can do this

```
var cached_data.Property1 = !(M.Property1 == cached_data.Property1) ?  M.Property1 : cached_data.Property1;
```

and now the table will update by

```
db.SaveChanges();
```